# GridView and Hyperlink

Tags: database, vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

I am new to VB and programming in general, however, I am currently trying to develop a simple application where you can add and save daily records to a database. One of the columns in the database table will be used to input paths/directories to files in my computer (e.g. C:\Users\M\Documents). When I type in the the file location and run the application the column contents is viewed as text and not a hyperlink. Could someone explain how to convert text in a specified column to hyperlinks (clickable)?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Are you using datagridview. then set column type  is `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`

Answer (score 0):

There is a column type DataGridViewLinkColumn, but you cannot edit the cells content at runtime in DataGridView (only from source code).

Another solution:

- Use DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column type.
- To link style: You can use the cell DefaultCellStyle property to make blue text.
- To mouse icon: You can handle the DataGridView's CellMouseEnter event to change the DataGridView.Cursor property when the mouse is over the link column.
- With the DataGridView's CellClick or CellContentClick event you can handle the click on link.